# What language similar to computer coding do undergrad philosophy majors learn?

Tags: education

Please see bold below. What "logic language" is this?

[Looking for a philosophy book... : LSAT](https://www.reddit.com/r/LSAT/comments/5nh96a/looking_for_a_philosophy_book/)

> It's not worth picking up a philosophy book for the LSAT, unless you're looking to build up your reading skills for RC [Reading Comprehension]. **Undergrad philosophy majors learn a logic language for translating arguments that's similar to computer coding.** Imo it's not worth learning, as LR [Legal Reasoning] arguments are quite basic, where the main challenge lies in eliminating trap answer choices, not understanding the argument itself.

Comment: [Propositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) and [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) calculus, what is called formal logic.

Comment: Legal arguments have a logical form or rather a variety of different logical forms. A logic text might help you to identify and assess the kinds of reasoning used in legal arguments. It wouldnt help with the content of legal reasoning but lawyers do use premises from which they derive conclusions and a logic text could help you to check examples of legal reasoning for valid derivation of conclusions from premises.

Comment: The language that your post addresses  is literally called "Mathematical logic". These days 99 percent of human beings just call it logic. Using such a shortcut is confusing because some students are not aware there are OTHER LOGICS. The Mathematical students seem to swear all logic is Mathematical & no other kind existed before Mathematical logic. Well Aristotelian logic was before Mathematical logic. Aristotelian logic is close to legal reasoning which is what the passage you quoted refers to. There are cases where logic is not Mathematical so it won't help 100 percent of the time.